# Implementing Google Calendar API with Angular 5

Tags: spring-boot, google-calendar-api, angular5

I'm trying to connect to the Google Calendar API using Angular 5 so that I can display upcoming events on the web application I am building.
I'm new in Angular and i'm looking for a way to integrate the API in my app.
I searched alot but i didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js start from here. Then from there you can start to Angular-ify it. We're not a free coding service. Ask a more specific question if you get stuck on a particular issue.

Comment: I'm also looking for this and can't find any solution, how do you Angular-ify somehting? I don't even know how to import script correctly

Answer (score 5):

Dealing with the similar task. This module works for me:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-calendar.

It connects you to an Google API and allows to retrieve, create, etc., events. And if you are also looking for the way to display gathered data, here's very nice calendar specifically for Angular 5:

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Unfortunately the calendar is not able to communicate with api on its own, so you would have to handle both managing api communication and handing it to the calendar.

There is also a possibility to use Fullcalendar with the google events, but I was not able to make it work with Angular 5 (not sure why):
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

Comment: Thanks for the links! Did you use JS, Node, or something else to connect with google-calender NPM mod?

Comment: Can you show some examples of how you made this work in A5? Thanks!